# What is the role and lifecycle of StateHelper?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I can see that EL attributes are stored in the `StateHelper` and String literals in the `getAttributes()` map of a component. What is the lifecycle and why the need for two containers?

Also at what points in the lifecycle are EL `ValueExpression` evaluated? (Every time the `getStateHelper.eval()` is called?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `StateHelper` provides a convenience for component developers (who subclass `UIComponent` directly and not a standard component) to maintain the state of a component across requests. It plays an integral role in JSF view state saving and the underlying contract provides more than just a means to stash component attributes.

   By subclassing `StateHelper`, a component developer can more conveniently key into the `saveState` and `restoreState` methods of `StateHolder`, methods which are supposed to guarantee that a component (and child components) have their state correctly persisted (per the configured state saving mode) of the JSF Impl.

   Contrast that with `getAttributes()` map which is basically a stash of component variables, and is mostly relevant during the lifecycle of a single request. It offers no other services than to keep stuff.
2. `ValueExpression` is evaluated **at least** 2x in a component's lifetime : `RESTORE_VIEW` and `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phases, for obvious reasons: The first to give appropriate rendering of components and the second, to commit validated and converted values to the backing bean

Comment: Well written. Thank you for detailing it in brief.